# Selecting RC filter components for half wave rectifier

Tags: adc, filter, rectifier, remote-control

I have a circuit where Input is a Sine pulse of 40V Amplitude and the circuit is as shown:[image]

After redtifier diode , there is a RC FILTER. I have used a tantalum capacitor and 0603 resistor. I was wondering if the size of the resistor is OK or i have to increase it for proper heat dissipation. After the filter, the output goes through a voltage divider into ADC input.

Comment: What is the purpose of your circuit? to measure the peak signal of the power line? what is the energy source attached to the left?

Comment: The input coming into the left is basically a transmitted pulse from a transformer with amplitude and current. So, the 50 ohm resistors act as voltage source impedance. The only purpose is to detect that the voltage is present. This is done by connecting the output of this circuit into ADC input.